# libiconv not linking to iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, iconv

I'm trying to compile [MailCore](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore) into an iOS app I'm making, and the linker keeps complaining that libiconv isn't linked in. At least that's what I think it's complaining about. This is what it spits out:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _mail_iconv in libmailcore.a(charconv.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _charconv in libmailcore.a(charconv.o)
      _charconv_buffer in libmailcore.a(charconv.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _charconv in libmailcore.a(charconv.o)
      _charconv_buffer in libmailcore.a(charconv.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(This is building for the simulator. Building for my iPhone gives the same error, but `s/i386/armv7/`).

I've tried adding `libiconv.dylib` to "Link Binary with Libraries", but it doesn't change the errors at all.

Any idea what could be wrong here? I've been trying to Google this error, but I can't find any information about how to link in libiconv. Since it's part of the iOS SDK, you would think I shouldn't need to compile it myself?

Comment: libiconv.dylib did it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As extra confirmation that the lib is included in your target, select the lib in the file list in the left pane of Xcode (assuming you've added it to your Target /  Project, you should see the framework listed under frameworks), and show the Assistant Editor view on the right pane (View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor).

Then, with the relevant lib selected on the left, you will see 'Target Membership' for that lib shown as a list of checkboxes on the right.

You should see App Target Listed, and the checkbox should be checked for that target.

You could try unchecking and rechecking it, to nudge it into your project?

Comment: Thanks, that did it! It was in the File Inspector though (Option-Cmd-1 in Xcode 4, or View > Utilities > Show File Inspector).

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for letting us know, and accepting the answer.

Comment: I have tried the same thing for libjumio library, but no use. Can you please help me how to resolve the issue for the same.

Answer (score 68):

You need add libiconv.dylib via "add framework". SRC is [available from this discussion.](http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/discussion/1072195/thread/5f8be82d#3388)

Answer (score 1):

- Simple:

  - use Xcode to add referenced framework: `libiconv`

    - `Xcode`->select **correct** project `Targets` -> `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary With Libraries`-> click **+** -> search `libiconv` -> select found `libiconv.tbd`
    - [image]
    - [image]
- detail: [my another post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734434/libiconv-or-iconv-undefined-symbol-on-mac-osx/72528782#72528782)

Comment: did that. But still the same issue. Correct target. :-(
I need static library.

Comment: found it. Somehow, I needed both. libiconv and iconv.