# How to build fat static library for armv6,armv7 and i386

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I followed the guide at [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4/3647187#3647187) to build the libmms ( https://github.com/kosher-penguin/xcode-libmms ), and got a fat static library, but it seems not work. I got errors when add the library to my project(xCode4.2+iOS5.0):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _mms_connect in libMMS.a(mms.o)
  "_Status_GetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
      _report_progress in libMMS.a(mms.o)
  "_Status_SetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
      _report_progress in libMMS.a(mms.o)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _string_utf16 in libMMS.a(mms.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _mms_connect in libMMS.a(mms.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Firstly,I clone the code from https://github.com/kosher-penguin/xcode-libmms.git 
Secondly, I open it with xCode4.2, and add the follow script to Run Script(Build Phases), and then run the project.
Thirdly, I copy the file named libmms.a  in the folder named Release-universal, and then add the library to a new project.
Fourthly, in the new project,add the header file from xcode-libmms project, import mms.h and mms_config.h, and call the function mms_connect, and then build it, but get the errors.

```
DEBUG_THIS_SCRIPT="false"

if [ $DEBUG_THIS_SCRIPT = "true" ]
then
echo "########### TESTS #############"
echo "Use the following variables when debugging this script; note that they may change on recursions"
echo "BUILD_DIR = $BUILD_DIR"
echo "BUILD_ROOT = $BUILD_ROOT"
echo "CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR"
echo "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR = $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"
echo "CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR = $CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR"
echo "TARGET_BUILD_DIR = $TARGET_BUILD_DIR"
fi

#####################[ part 1 ]##################
# First, work out the BASESDK version number (NB: Apple ought to report this, but they hide it)
#    (incidental: searching for substrings in sh is a nightmare! Sob)

SDK_VERSION=$(echo ${SDK_NAME} | grep -o '.\{3\}$')

# Next, work out if we're in SIM or DEVICE

if [ ${PLATFORM_NAME} = "iphonesimulator" ]
then
OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD=iphoneos${SDK_VERSION}
else
OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD=iphonesimulator${SDK_VERSION}
fi

echo "XCode has selected SDK: ${PLATFORM_NAME} with version: ${SDK_VERSION} (although back-targetting: ${IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET})"
echo "...therefore, OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD = ${OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD}"
#
#####################[ end of part 1 ]##################

#####################[ part 2 ]##################
#
# IF this is the original invocation, invoke WHATEVER other builds are required
#
# Xcode is already building ONE target...
#
# ...but this is a LIBRARY, so Apple is wrong to set it to build just one.
# ...we need to build ALL targets
# ...we MUST NOT re-build the target that is ALREADY being built: Xcode WILL CRASH YOUR COMPUTER if you try this (infinite recursion!)
#
#
# So: build ONLY the missing platforms/configurations.

if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: I am NOT the root invocation, so I'm NOT going to recurse"
else
# CRITICAL:
# Prevent infinite recursion (Xcode sucks)
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

echo "RECURSION: I am the root ... recursing all missing build targets NOW..."
echo "RECURSION: ...about to invoke: xcodebuild -configuration \"${CONFIGURATION}\" -target \"${TARGET_NAME}\" -sdk \"${OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD}\" ${ACTION} RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO"
xcodebuild -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -sdk "${OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD}" ${ACTION} RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

ACTION="build"

#Merge all platform binaries as a fat binary for each configurations.

# Calculate where the (multiple) built files are coming from:
CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR=${SYMROOT}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos
CURRENTCONFIG_SIMULATOR_DIR=${SYMROOT}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator

echo "Taking device build from: ${CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR}"
echo "Taking simulator build from: ${CURRENTCONFIG_SIMULATOR_DIR}"

CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR=${SYMROOT}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
echo "...I will output a universal build to: ${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}"

# ... remove the products of previous runs of this script
#      NB: this directory is ONLY created by this script - it should be safe to delete!

rm -rf "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}"
mkdir "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}"

#
echo "lipo: for current configuration (${CONFIGURATION}) creating output file: ${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}"
lipo -create -output "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" "${CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" "${CURRENTCONFIG_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}"

#########
#
# Added: StackOverflow suggestion to also copy "include" files
#    (untested, but should work OK)
#
if [ -d "${CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR}/usr/local/include" ]
then
mkdir -p "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/usr/local/include"
# * needs to be outside the double quotes?
cp "${CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR}/usr/local/include/"* "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/usr/local/include"
fi
fi
```

Please give me some help, thank you.

update:
After add libiconv library, the error as follow:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_Status_GetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
      _report_progress in libMMS.a(mms.o)
  "_Status_SetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
      _report_progress in libMMS.a(mms.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Show us how you created your library please.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is that your library has a dependency on `libiconv`. When you use your library, you should not just add `libMMS` but `libiconv` as well, which comes with any XCode installation. See [libiconv not linking to iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464851/libiconv-not-linking-to-ios-project) for how to add it to the project.

I don't know what dependency `_Status_GetNewStatusByKey` and `_Status_SetNewStatusByKey`. They might be similar.

**Update:**

The second problem is the function `report_progress()` in `mms.c` that uses the functions `Status_GetNewStatusByKey` and `Status_SetNewStatusByKey`, which don't seem to be defined anywhere (didn't you get warnings when you compiled the library?). Remove everything that declares, defines or uses `report_progress()`. It has been removed in the latest version of libmms anyway.

Comment: thank you, as you said, after add libiconv, the error:Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_Status_GetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
      _report_progress in libMMS.a(mms.o)
  "_Status_SetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
      _report_progress in libMMS.a(mms.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: ,thank you very much, it can be build now, but I still go an error where run. The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS on _malloc_initialize.

Comment: Codo, would you like to help me to build a fat library for the source code at https://launchpad.net/libmms, thank you.

Comment: I don't think I can help you with your latest error. It's rather different from the initial problem. You'd better start a new question that focuses on the latest error. And to help find the cause, you'll need to add a full stack trace and the affected code to your question.