# Apache Cordova - don't build i386 architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova, cordova-3

I'm getting an error in my build (using cordova 3.4):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::string&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, char const*) in zxing-all-in-one.o
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::string&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, char const*) in zxing-all-in-one.o
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::string&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, char const*) in zxing-all-in-one.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **
```

I'm pretty sure this comes from the phone gap QR scanner plugin, but I don't think it should be building i386 at all. The qrcode scanner seems not to have a library of that architecture.

How can I tell cordova not to build i386? Or did i miss something?

Comment: did u add all frameworks that needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you build you can specify what type of build to do:

```
cordova compile --device
```

or for i386:

```
cordova compile --emulator
```

That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: Not sure how it fixed it for you. Modern macs are x86_64 and I (like others) build my library without the i386 slice. --device does works just as you said though.

Comment: I figure it has something to do with the emulators we have configured. I haven't had this issue since using later versions of cordova

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a few days too. I followed the guidance in Snips answer here to get it working for me

[libiconv not linking to iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464851/libiconv-not-linking-to-ios-project)