# Cordova ignores the specified architecture when building on IOS

Tags: xcode, cordova, phonertc

I'm trying to build the PhoneRTC demo on IOS after managing to get it to work on Android and web browser (OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite, XCode 6.1.1, Cordova 4.2.0 and my iPad is running iOS 8.1). My iPad is plugged in. I followed the installation steps for IOS:

1. In General, change Deployment Target to 7.0 or above
2. Go to Build Settings and change:

   - a. Valid Architectures => armv7
   - b. Build Active Architecture Only => No
   - c. Runpath Search Paths => $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
   - d. Objective-C Bridging Header => [ProjectName]/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/Bridging-Header.h
   - e. Embedded content contains Swift Code => yes

I repeated steps 4a. - 4c. for the CordovaLib project as well.

When I run `cordova build ios`, the build fails. In the console, I see this:

```
Build settings from command line:
ARCHS = i386
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/Francis/Desktop/PhoneRTC/PhoneRTC/platforms/ios/build/emulator
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.1
SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/Francis/Desktop/PhoneRTC/PhoneRTC/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
VALID_ARCHS = i386
```

This seems to indicate that cordova is ignoring the valid architectures I just specified. I tried rebooting my PC and my iPad also but that didn't help. `cordova build ios --archs="armv7"` doesn't work either.

Buiding from within XCode works, but that's not what I want since it skips the cordova build process.

**Any idea how to tell/force Cordova to build against the architecture (armv7) I specified?**

Comment: Use `cordova prepare` and then build from `xcode`. This is a common build path for custom iOS setting needs.

Comment: Yep that fixed my problem! And you helped me better understand the cordova build process at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: Adding this as an answer for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `cordova prepare` and then build from `Xcode`.

`cordova prepare` copies files and config settings but does not modify the native code or try to run the standard build process.

This is a common build path that I have used with all of my iOS/Cordova projects and seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

Use an xcconfig configuration file
During automated build, I create the file after my build script adds the iOS platform:

> echo 'ARCHS=armv7 arm64' >> ${CURR_DIR}/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig

An excerpt from build logs:

```
> cordova build ios --device --release 

...
Build settings from configuration file '/Users/xxx/git/xxx/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig':
        ARCHS = armv7 arm64
        CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = XXXX
        ENABLE_BITCODE = true
        PROVISIONING_PROFILE = XXXX
        VALID_ARCHS = armv7 arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948917/apache-cordova-dont-build-i386-architecture) this is the solution (worked for me)

When you build you can specify what type of build to do:

```
cordova compile --device
```

or for i386:

```
cordova compile --emulator
```